# Codeigniter safe queries and xss clean

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I try to remake methods which got queries from ids to methods which work with slugs.

So basically this:

```
public function view($id)
{
 $id = (int)$id;
 $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('recipes')
}
```

To this:

```
public function view($slug)
{
   $this->db->where('slug', $slug)->get('recipes')
}
```

In the second method I'm aware that this is a xss not safe. I think that it will be best to remake all queries with query bindings.

Like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

But I have too munch queries to remake is it possible to have some function whic to clean the slug from the codeigniter or something in the second method example?

Is it ok to use the security xss-clean method to the slug before to use it in the query:

```
$this->security->xss_clean($slug)
```

Comment: The use of `$this->db->where('slug', $slug)->get('recipes')` creates the exact same results as `$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));` The second method is way more efficient because you won't run hundreds of lines of code to get to the exact same query. The `view($id)`example has the effect of sanitizing the input (`$id`) because of the cast to int. That will eliminate the possible SQL injection attacks you are trying to prevent. `xss_clean()` will remove disallowed characters too and is also acceptable - but not as efficient.

Comment: I'm aware of all of this except for the xss_clean is it good to use it.  They are too many methods which i need to remake, so i want not to test everything again, because it is written from other developers. So I think with the xss_clean i will have what i want. Save queries but easy to remake all the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess all insert or update data come from a form, if you go to application/config/config.php and set

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FASLE;
```

to

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

this helpyou to filter all inputs (xss_clean)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function view($slug)
{
   $slug_new=$this->db->escape_str(trim($slug));
   $this->db->where('slug', $slug_new)->get('recipes')
}
```

Comment: This will only escape the string nothing else.